# Polyphase merge sort for sorting a large text file

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I want to sort a text file with a few million of these algorithms to use.

My programming language is C#.

Its structure txt file is as follows:

```
for instance          desired Result
------------          ---------------      
  723,80                 1,4   
  14,50                  1,5 
  723,2                  10,8
  1,5                   14,50 
  10,8                  723,2 
  1,4                   723,80
```

**At the same time, and memory is very important to me.**

This algorithm is suitable for the job?

If appropriate, please give an explanation of this algorithm.
And give an example

Thank you.

Comment: For a few million lines (I think you meant lines rather than algorithms) of the kind you show, the in-memory quicksort from the C# library will be fine unless you are running in a very restricted environment.

Comment: 5 million lines in a text file

Comment: What's wrong about the built-in sort algorithm? It's quicksort, which is among the fastest algorithms. Or do you need an external, disk-based sort?

Comment: @gandolf Okay 5 million lines with less than 10 chars each is 50 megabytes or 100 megabytes with 16-bit chars.  Read the file into an array of strings. Sort the array.  Write them back. I agree with Hynek that GNU sort is great for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can fit the data in memory, the in-built quicksort is likely going to be fast enough.

As suggested in another answer, using the unix utility `sort` is a very good alternative. I've used it in the past to test files with over 100,000,000 lines with runtimes of seconds.

Finally, if your dataset is truly gigantic, what you can do is the following

1. Split the data into different files of an acceptable size
2. Sort each file independently using quicksort, for example. You can parallelize this on more computers if you need (keep in mind that transferring a file has a cost, too!)
3. Do a [parallel merge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm) of the results using only a small memory buffer and dumping the data to disk. This can be done on many files concurrently.

Comment: This is an interesting idea.

This method does not affect the speed of sorting?http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting

Answer (score 1):

In case of being in-place (so no additional memory used) **merge-sort might not be the best choice**, as its standard implementations use linear-amount of additional memory.

**Quicksort**, in its standard implementations, does not use additional memory, except for the memory for recursive calls (with good implementation that stack-memory is O(logn) so it should not be a great problem).

You may also consider using **Heap-Sort** (being in-place, O(nlogn), never quadratic), if you do not mind your algorithm being unstable (may exchange elements with the same value - Note that Quickosort is usually not-stable as well.) Heapsort may also need some stack-memory for recursive calls, but usually not as much as QuickSort does.

I do not include description of QuickSort or HeapSort, because they are very well documented online or in books. Examples may be found in many languages, including C#, of course.

Answer (score 1):

For this task I would use [`sort`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html) from GNU project. With right locale and `-n` would do the job and I doubt you will beat this battle tested program with not so big effort. You can even utilize all your cores and sort files far bigger than your RAM.

Comment: This is an algorithm question on programming site. If you're going to suggest a tool / command-line command, you should probably also explain how it works.